# background color in a ImageButton

Tags: android, imagebutton

I put a background color in a ImageButton? How?

Answer (score 7):

```
android:background="#rrggbb"
```

in XML file with layout definition, then use PNG file with transparency as image source

Comment: a transparent background can be done like this...     android:background="#00000000"

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere `android:background="@null"`

Answer (score 6):

You can use  *android:background=" "*  to set the color of ImageButton and some android widgets.
('#rrggbb' or '@android.color/blue', '@android:color/transparent').
 you can follow this example as your reference.

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnGreen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/my_image.png"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **android:backgroundTint** insted of android:background[image]

```
<ImageButton
   android:id="@+id/imgImageTab"
   android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
   android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
   android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_home"
   android:backgroundTint="@color/blue" />
```